# Website on Mobile device display half width for 10 seconds then changes to normal?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, width

Ok so the website I am having issues with is http://Laf-Laf.com

When you view the site from a mobile device it loads the home page at half width but if given ten seconds the page will fill in to full width and look fine.  I cannot figure out why the page is loading half size before it loads to full width and why it is taking so long to load to full width.

Anyone ever come across this issue or have any ideas?  I will gladly provide the code if someone can possibly tell me what code to be looking for to fix this issue.

---

The issue was resolved. I found that it was a problem with revolution slider and having an image on top of an image.  I edited the image file to be one single image and it doesn't look quite the same but now it functions and it is loading instantly on both full browser and on mobile browsers.

Comment: They may be issue of javascript that load after some time and render half page !!!

Comment: Where are your styles referenced on your html? Header or footer?

Comment: the stylesheets are referenced in the header.  If its an issue of javascript how would i find it and correct it?